# How to check if string contains all of strings in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, matcher

I have

```
last_email_sent.body.should include "Company Name"
last_email_sent.body.should include "SomeCompany"
last_email_sent.body.should include "Email"
last_email_sent.body.should include "test@test.pl"
```

And I would like to replace it using array

```
last_email_sent.body.should include ["test@test.pl", "Email"]
```

Comment: What does `last_email_sent.body` look like?

Comment: It is multiline string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply loop:

```
["test@test.pl", "Email"].each { |str| last_email_sent.body.should include str }
```

Or if you like the matcher syntax, write your own matcher:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :include_all do |include_items|
  match do |given|
    @errors = include_items.reject { |item| given.include?(item) }
    @errors.empty?
  end

  failure_message_for_should do |given|
    "did not include \"#{@errors.join('\", \"')}\""
  end

  failure_message_for_should_not do |given|
     "everything was included"
  end

  description do |given|
    "includes all of #{include_items.join(', ')}"
  end
end
```

Invoke it like this:

```
last_email_sent.body.should include_all ["test@test.pl", "Email"]
```

Comment: Note first posting did not work, the `|include_items|` input needs to go on the whole matcher definition

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to reverse that matcher to ``should not include any``

Comment: @regedarek: Mainly you'd need to watch for double-negatives. Just implement a new matcher include_any (because `should_not include_all` is not same as `should include_any`), and make the `failure_message_for_should_not` be a bit more useful than I did above. Hint: You won't be able to use the @errors array in the positive case, so `match` block should be really really simple . . .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
["test@test.pl", "Email"].all?{ |str| last_email_sent.body[str] }.should == true
```

Comment: Then maybe cleaner will be: ``be_in_body.each {|string| last_email_sent.body.should include string}``

Answer (score 1):

I like to put arrays like that in a utility method:

**spec/support/utilities.rb**

```
def email_body_elements
  ["Company Name", "Some Company", "Email", "test@test.pl"]
end
```

**spec/your_spec.rb**

```
email_body_elements.each do |element|
  last_email_sent.body.should include element
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `last_email_sent.body` is exactly `Company Name SomeCompany test@test.pl Email`:

```
last_email_sent.body.should include ["Company Name", "SomeCompany", "test@test.pl", "Email"].join(" ")
```